# Kibana slider for price filtering

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I have a Elasticsearch index with products and prices and i want to filter prices in a convient way. 
With Kibana i already created very nice dashboard and i'm using custom defined price charts to allow filtering of prices.
The price charts are not flexible enough. Because of this i'm searching for a more flexible aproach to adjust the prices.

Is there a posibility to use sliders in Kibana?

Comment: Consider rephrasing your question to be more specific. See: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic  "general computing hardware and software are off-topic"

Comment: You might want to try this plugin: https://github.com/raystorm-place/kibana-slider-plugin

Comment: @Val: Thank you. This plugin is exactly what i was searching for.